# What is the best way to test my anomaly detection system?

Tags: ids, detection, intrusion

I have an IDS (Intrusion Detection System) built in C and I need to test it with real traffic. It is an anomaly detection system, so I need to train it with normal traffic first.

The IDS that I built is called MAIS-IDS and it is originally tested against the NSL KDD dataset. This IDS is from the article "MAIS-IDS: A distributed intrusion detection system using multi-agent AIS approach".

The first thing I need to do is to convert the tcpdump data to NSL KDD 99 dataset so I can analyze the traffic in real time. In my research I saw that I could use `tcpreplay`, `tshark`, or another option is to write my own script. I would like to know what is the best way of doing that.

After that, I'm going to use my IDS together with graph attack built through the software `mulval` in order to reduce the false positives.

To test everything I'm going to use Metasploit which is a framework that I could use in order to write scripts to attack my network.

The other thing I would like to know is if this software that I'm going to use is the best way of doing that. I'm kind of lost my first time trying to prepare this kind of experiment.

Comment: To test it in a real environment, why not just set up a honeypot?

Comment: Rule number one of assessing one's security is to not test it yourself. Anyone can come up with a system they can't break themselves. The true test is whether someone else can find a way in. Other than that, I'm not really sure what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @Luc ok... lets focus on the first part than... I have an anomaly IDS and like I said I need to convert tcpdump data into NSL KDD. So being more specific I need to get from tcpdump data, network attributes as: duration, service, flag,  src_bytes, dst_bytes, wrong_fragment, urgent, hot, num_failed_logins, num_compromised, su_attempted, num_root, num_file_creations, num_shells, num_access files, count, srv_count, dst_host_count, dst_host_srv_count.

Comment: Using the tool tshark is the best way for doing this? Is that even possible through this tool or is there another better way? Becuse that is the way I pretend to convert tcpdump to NSL KDD